# How to find Mongodb documents and display the results according to select box filters

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Assume that all my documents are in the same collection, and none of them are nested. I am using Node.js.

Here's some dummy data.

```js
firstName: "Pippa",
lastName: "Smith"
preferredSalutation: "Mrs"
mobileNumber: "123123"
emailAddress:"pippasmith@gmail.com"
```

I am trying to accomplish three things.

1. Find the correct Mongo query to search for specific fields in a collection of documents that will be displayed in a table. The table has drop down select boxes beside it that the user can use to filter the results displayed in the table. For now, assume the filters are `firstName`, `lastName` and `preferredSalutation`. The query needs to either return the appropriate match, or nothing. Currently the type of `firstName` is a `String`, as it is for all other fields.
2. If the user selects more than one filter, for example `firstName` and `mobileNumber`, then the table should display *only* the documents that match these two filters. Everything else should be excluded until...
3. The user selects the `Show all` option in the filter dropdown which removes the given filter for that field and updates the results in the table.

I have tried to use `.find()` with little success because I struggle to sort the results in the table so that only documents that match all the filter selections are displayed. I tried `.aggregate()` and but it seems like it may be overkill given that I don't wish to join collections.

Would appreciate some thoughts on the best way to do this.

Comment: `find(query)` is all you need. Have you read the mongo docs?

Comment: No, I pulled the previous attempts at `.find()` and `.aggregate()` from a chest at the bottom of my bed. What are docs?

Comment: assuming you have a user defined set of filters, `firstName` and `mobileNumber`, `.find({firstName: firstName, mobileNumber: mobileNumber})` will return exactly that.